# Java mysql next result from stored procedure

Tags: java, mysql, sockets

I have following stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `blast10`()
BEGIN
SELECT concat("ROUND ",draws.izvlacenje_id,": ", draws.1,",",draws.2,",",draws.3,",",draws.4,",",draws.5,",",draws.6,",",draws.7,",",draws.8,",",draws.9,",",draws.10,",",draws.11,",",draws.12,",",draws.13,",",draws.14,",\n",draws.15,",",draws.16,",",draws.17,",",draws.18,",",draws.19,",",draws.20,",",
draws.21,",",draws.22,",",draws.23,",",draws.24,",",draws.25,",",draws.26,",",draws.27,",",draws.28,",",draws.29,",",draws.30,",",draws.31,",",draws.32,",",draws.33,",",draws.34,",",draws.35,"")
rzlt from macau.draws order by iddraws desc limit 10;
END`
```

This procedure returns 10 rows of data and i want to send that data through TCP/IP communication, this is what i achieved by now:

```
public void blastTen() throws SQLException {
    String blastTen = "";
    String bl10 = "LAST 10 RESULTS";
    try {
        Statement st = Conex.conn.createStatement();
        String SQLEdit = "{ call blast10() }";
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(SQLEdit);
        while (rs.next()) {
            blastTen = bl10 + "\n" + rs.getString("rzlt") + "\n";
        }
        os.println(blastTen + "\n");
    }
    catch (Exception e2) {
        System.out.println(e2);
    }
}
```

The problem is I can send only one row and can't seem to get the other rows.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Flaws in both the SQL and Java code.  Relational design not normalized.  Java doesn't close resources.  Ugly code.  Run the query without Java to see if you get more than one row.

Comment: Aside from duffymo's comments you don't really do anything in the read loop, rs.getString() will return the current row value each time round - i.e. that line of code runs for each row

Comment: Without java i do get rows but can't fetch them in Java... I know the code is messy and everything but i'm still learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code

```
while (rs.next())
{
    blastTen=bl10+"\n"+rs.getString("rzlt")+"\n";
}
```

won't assign anything to `bl10` so you'll always only get the latest row... Try

```
   ...
   bl10 = bl10 + "\n" + rs.getString( "rzlt" );
}
os.println( bl10 );
```

instead.

Cheers,